# breqn doesn't manage to fully break my equation

Tags: breqn

I'm trying to use the `breqn` package to add automatic line breaks to a particular equation. It gives me three line breaks in the example below, then gives up and lets the equation trail off the page. Is there any way to fix this, short of manually breaking the lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
F(T_1, T_2) = T_1 + T_2 + u_0^{-2} (x_1 u_0 + 2 u_1) C_2(T_1, T_2) 
+ u_0^{-4} (x_1 u_0 u_1 - 2 u_1^2)C_3(T_1, T_2) 
+ ((4 x_2 u_0^3 - 2 x_1 u_0 u_1^2 + 4 u_1^3 + 4 u_0^2 u_2)/u_0^6) T_1^3 T_2 
+ ((x_1^2 u_0^2 u_1 + 6 x_2 u_0^3 - 3 x_1 u_0 u_1^2 + 2 u_1^3 
+ 6 u_0^2 u_2)/u_0^6) T_1^2 T_2^2 + ((4 x_2 u_0^3 - 2 x_1 u_0 u_1^2 + 4 u_1^3 
+ 4 u_0^2 u_2)/u_0^6) T_1 T_2^3 + ((-4 x_2 u_0^3 u_1 + 5 x_1 u_0 u_1^3 
+ 3 x_1 u_0^3 u_2 - 10 u_1^4 - 14 u_0^2 u_1 u_2)/u_0^8) T_1^4 T_2 + \cdots
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

I'm not concerned for now with the typographic quality of the output; I just want to be able to see the whole equation. And I want to avoid manually setting the breaks, because the equation I'm trying to set is *really* long--about ten times the length of the equation above.

Comment: It seems that breqn is not able to cope with breaks past a certain point.